# Inline javascript being called twice in replaced HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm inserting a map into a `div` element using the *Mapbox* library and its [recommended](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/simple-map/), inline javascript:

```
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'token';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', // stylesheet location
    center: [-74.50, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});
</script>
```

Seperate from this, I parse the page for certain patterns and execute a `replace` function on any matches via *jquery* like:

```
$("div.comp").contents().each(function () {
    var $html = $(this).html();
    $replaced = $html.replace(/\[\?\]/g, "?");
    $replaced = $replaced.replace(... etc);
    $(this).html($replaced);
});
```

The patterns are irrelevant to the *Mapbox* inline javascript and don't interfere with it other than creating a side-effect that took a while for me to find what was causing it. Basically, the inline script is getting executd twice. Once, when the page loads, and a second time when my *jquery* replace function returns the `html` with relevant strings replaced and the `<script>` code intact.

### Possible and Failed Solutions:

I realise I could solve this by straying from the recommended *Mapbox* method and using the more universally recommended method of calling javascript from an external file. I would like to avoid this for the simple reason that I'm using some condtional `PHP` to execute or ignore certain parts of the *Mapbox* code, relevant to `PHP` variables earlier on the page.

Instead, I added an additional replacement into my *jquery function* which, if any `<script>` tags were found, replaced them with a blank string so that they weren't executed in the returned HTML:

```
$replaced = $replaced.replace(/<script>[\s\S]+?<\/script>/g, "");
```

While this appears to work with certain bits of code (a call to `console.log` only gets called once now rather than twice) the map no longer renders. I'm guessing that, perhaps, it didn't execute fully before the `<script>` tag was replaced with nothing.

I could look at adding *on.complete* conditions, etc. but this all seems needlessly over-complicated. Is there a more elegant solution I'm missing to ensure this inline script is only executed once while being able to execute my string replace function simultaneously? Otherwise I may just look at trying to run *Mapbox* from an external js file and translate the `PHP` conditions into `javascript`.

---

On a related, but separate note. I didn't think that returning html with a `<script>` tag would execute the code inside it on return, only on page load. Is it that it's partially executing when the page loads, doesn't have time to complete when its replaced, and loads it again?

Comment: You shouldn't be using a RegEx to handle an HTML String. Just leaving that out there.

Comment: You can use a hack - create a global variable `hasExecuted` and set it to `true` after first run. Also wrap the inlined JS into IF Clause `if (!hasExecuted) {....}`. It is definitely dirty method, but it should work

Comment: There is probably no clean solution for what you are trying to do. Well.. is PHP after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments above, it would appear that there may not be a more elegant way of solving the issue. This was the least convoluted way I could think of solving this:

I moved the inline script to an external file and was able to translate the conditional `PHP` arguments into javascript. I also translated several needed variables by describing them as `data attributes` on the `div` element where I was inserting the map. From these, my javascript could create its own replacement variables that I needed to provide to *Mapbox*.